# C# Xamarin - Application crashes, when dismiss ProgressDialog

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, progressdialog

I'm developing an android Xamarin application. My application connects to my website and because it lasts to long, I use `ProgressDialog`. But when `ProgressDialog` dismiss, application crashes. I don't see why. I tried to catch error, but application crashed too. *(Sorry for my english)*

**Here is code:**

```
ProgressDialog load;
void FTPConnection()
        {
            load = new ProgressDialog(this);
            load.SetTitle("Načítání");
            load.SetMessage("Spojování s ftp://kolemzeme.wz.cz, může to chvíli trvat...");
            load.SetCancelable(false);
            load.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
            load.Show();

            new Thread(new ThreadStart(async delegate
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                try
                {
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://" + web);
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + web + "/cesta.txt");
                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(web, pass);
                    request.UseBinary = true;
                    request.UsePassive = true;
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
                    try
                    {
                        FtpWebResponse respose = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                        {
                            load.Dismiss();
                        });
                        NaCeste();
                    }
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {
                        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                        {
                            load.Dismiss();
                        });
                        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Cesta);
                        Cesta();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    RunOnUiThread(() => 
                    {
                        load.Dismiss();
                    });
                    load.Dismiss();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.SetTitle("Nelze se připojit na FTP!")
                           .SetMessage("Aplikace nemůže navázat přístup k serveru FTP: http://kolemzeme.wz.cz\n\nPravděpodobně nemáte internet, nebo je server nyní nedostupný. Zkuste to později.\n\nError: " + ex.Message)
                           .SetCancelable(false)
                           .SetPositiveButton("Připojit se k wifi", delegate
                           {
                               Intent i = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionWifiSettings);
                               StartActivityForResult(i, 0);
                               FTPConnection();

                           })
                           .SetNeutralButton("Opakovat", delegate
                           {
                               FTPConnection();
                           })
                           .SetNegativeButton("Odejít", delegate
                           {
                               Finish();
                           })
                           .Show();
                }
            })).Start();
        }
```

Screenshot of error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aivqz.jpg).

Comment: Since you are starting a new thread, make sure your call `.Dismiss` on the UI thread, i.e. something like `this.RunOnUiThread(() => { load.Dismiss(); });` (`this` would be your activity...) (On UI creation/updates/etc... need to be placed on the UI Looper thread)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still not working.

Comment: Can you show us your code (update your post) with your code after making the suggested change?

Comment: Ok, i edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RunOnUiThread(() => 
{
    load.Dismiss();
});
load.Dismiss();
```

You have one `Dismiss` call running on the UI thread, and one not. You need to remove the second one.

Even better would be to move **all** of your exception processing to the UI thread. So change:

```
RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    load.Dismiss();
});
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Cesta);
Cesta();
```

to:

```
RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    load.Dismiss();
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Cesta);
    Cesta();
});
```

(as an example - you will need to make this style of change to all of your catch blocks)

Comment: When I start application, it shows `ProgressDialog` and after few seconds application crases. Screenhot of error is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aivqz.jpg)

Comment: The code in that screenshot does not contain the code changes I suggested. Can you show a screenshot with the code changes I suggested?

Comment: Oh sorry, it was old screenshot. [There](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l28V.png) is new screenshot of error.

Comment: I didn't see that you change your solution. Now it's working, thank you very much!